# Android convert string to LocaleCurrency

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, currency

I saved in the database, the string "Locale.CHINA." 
Now when I do the query I would like to assign to the TextView, the Currency Locale.CHINA, so I should convert the string to LOCAL, is it possible?

```
NumberFormat ca = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale...);
String dato = ca.format(valoredouble);
tv.setText(dato);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is save the language and country from the locale as strings. Then when you load that data construct your locale data using those strings `Locale (String language, String country)`. [Here's the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for you to take a look at.

Edit:
One of the easiest ways to save the currency the user has selected would be in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Just save it like this:

> SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
>   prefs.edit().putString("currency_code", ca.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode()).commit();

and load it like this:

> SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
>   ca.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(prefs.getString("currency_code", defaultCurrency)));

Comment: I would like to allow users to choose the currency. I'm thinking of different solutions, which do you think is the best?

Comment: to load the currency I have done so:
`NumberFormat ca = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  String defaultCurrency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getCurrencyCode();
  ca.setCurrency(sharedPrefs.getString("code", defaultCurrency)); `

but in NumberFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: You use `Currency.getInstance(String currencyCode)` to fix that. If this helped please accept the answer via the green checkmark on the left